# DC motor with encoder

Tags: motor, quadrature-encoder

Can anyone help me out here with this DC motor, especially the encoder part? I tried searching around for its datasheet but its as short as 1 page and the only spec I get are:

Encoder:
1 pulse/revolution

It has 2 connection on the bottom, and I guess they are for driving the motor, but they say nothing about the 3 connections wires below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Answer (score 3):

Besides referring to the previously-mentioned [82860502 pdf file](http://www.crouzet.com/english/catalog/dc-motors-dc-direct-drive-brushed-motors-32-mm-3-9-watts-3-9-w-with-tags-Part%20number-82860502.pdf), see pages 30 and 31 of Steven Engineering's [44MICRO-MOTORS.pdf file](http://stevenengineering.com/tech_support/PDFs/44MICRO-MOTORS.pdf), where the following diagram appears and shows the usage of the brown, yellow, and blue wires.

[image: encoder wiring diagram]

Attach a V+ voltage (for example, 5VDC) to the brown wire and connect the blue wire to ground.  As the motor rotates, the yellow wire will alternately be pulled up to V+ through a 10K resistor, and to ground via an NPN transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Crouzet's 82860502 documentation](http://www.crouzet.com/english/catalog/dc-motors-dc-direct-drive-brushed-motors-32-mm-3-9-watts-3-9-w-with-tags-Part%20number-82860502.pdf#zoom=100) doesn't seem to be very helpful.

According to [this post on their forum](http://www.crouzet-usa.com/techtalk/lofiversion/index.php/t145.html), the wiring is as follows:

- Brown wire: + VDC encoder supply
- Yellow wire: encoder output signal
- Blue wire: encoder ground